# No reference id found for related field odoo 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to relate many2one field to another many2one field but return error.

I used on create method didn't work, I tried

```
jounral = field.Many2one('erp.journal', related="journal_item.journal
```

worked but on upgrade of database I receive error

> There is no reference field journal_id found of journal.entries.

Here is my code

```
class JournalItem(models.Model):
_name = 'journal.item'

name = fields.Char()
journal = fields.Many2one('erp.journal')
entries = fields.One2many('journal.entries', 'journal_item')


class JournalEntries(models.Model):
    _name = 'journal.entries'

    #record Created but didn't work
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        vals['journal_id'] = self.journal_item.journal
        return super(JournalEntries, self).create(vals)

    #Error NoneType object has no attribute 'id'
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        for x in self:
            x.journal_id = x.journal_item.journal
            return super(JournalEntries, self).create(vals)

    journal_item = fields.Many2one('journal.item')
    journal_id = fields.Many2one('erp.journal')
```

Answer (score 0):

Very first you need to understand the **@api** decorators usage, which decorators should be implemented when.

**@api.model**  does not have any list of recordset, so you can not loop through it.

You can easily achieve this by defining relational field.

```
class JournalEntries(models.Model):
    _name = 'journal.entries'

    journal_item = fields.Many2one('journal.item')
    journal_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='erp.journal', related='journal_item.journal', string='Journal', readonly=True)
```

[Click here to read about **@api** decorators](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decorator.html)

Comment: I tried this way as mentioned it works but while upgrading module i receive error (there is no reference field 'journal_id' found for 'journal.entries')

Comment: Comment out create method code first, upgrade module and paste log in question with __init__.py file. Error seems only in create methods.